# Why do Java classfiles (and JNI) use a "Frankenstein's monster" encoding crossing UTF-8 and UTF-16?

Tags: java

It seems like using either UTF-16 or UTF-8 would have been a lot more straightforward than what Java decided on for storing strings in classfiles and JNI payloads.  It is a monstrosity that combines aspects of UTF-16 and UTF-8 formats.  Is there any rational explanation for choosing this option?

See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jni/types.html

It seems to me that this unique format is what you would get if you started with UTF-16, then passed that through a "**UCS-2** to UTF-8" converter... in other words, something you'd only produce by mistake... a variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake (albeit one that is lossless).

I have since discovered that there is a name for this format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8. (However the Java string format is technically a small extension of CESU-8 to add "overlong null bytes" and this extended version of CESU-8 has its own [vague] name: ‘Modified UTF-8’).

Comment: Would the fact that Java was originally designed to work with UCS-2 be a clue as to why things might be stored as they are?

Comment: I believe Java (first released in 1995) predates UTF-16 (standardized in 1996), but I'm not sure if it also predates UTF-8 (I see one RFC from 1996, but I don't know if it existed before). I do believe that UCS-2 was also the internal encoding for the Windows OS to properly support Asian languages, but I don't know how prevalent UCS-2 was elsewhere, and I also don't know what the specific reason was why Java chose it - but my educated guess (hence not an answer): In 1995, UCS-2 was the best thing available to support international languages without resorting to codepages.

Comment: this isn't retro is it?  why not ask this over at SO itself?

Comment: i don't get where you get the idea it's a combination of UTF-8 and UTF-16?  The document you linked is clear: It's UTF-8, except it doesn't represent the full range and it does something non-standard with embedded nulls.  Did I misunderstand you, or the document?

Comment: The document, in particular it seems like you did not read the part starting with "Characters with code points above U+FFFF".

Comment: The nonstandardness is in the handling of UTF-16 surrogate pairs.  "Proper" UTF-8 would require you to combine the surrogates to get one codepoint, then UTF-8-encode that.  The Java approach independently encodes each surrogate (and thus ends up with two 3-byte units rather than one 4-byte unit). When the standard programmer-visible datatype 'appears to be' UTF-16, this is probably a win.  Having written my share of encoding-converters, it seems to me to be a reasonable approach.

Comment: @davidbak, SO is notoriously hostile to "why" questions, especially involving "history"

Comment: Java uses Unicode.  How this is encoded into bytes depends on how and where it is used.

Comment: @davidbak We already have one Java question, and it wasn’t closed: <https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18143/15334>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> It seems to me that this unique format is what you would get if you started with UTF-16, then passed that through a "UCS-2 to UTF-8" converter.

As I understand it:

From a modern viewpoint UTF-16 and UCS-2 are different encodings, but historically it makes more sense to think of them as different versions of the same encoding. What is now called "UCS-2" was historically just called "Unicode".

Back in 1989 the ISO had proposed a Universal character set as a draft of ISO 10646, but the major software vendors did not like it, seeing it as over-complicated. They devised their own system called Unicode, a fixed-width 16-bit encoding. The software companies convinced a sufficient number of national standards bodies to vote down the draft of ISO 10646 and ISO was pushed into unification with Unicode.

This original 16-bit Unicode was adopted as the native internal format by a number of major software products. Two of the most notable were Java (released in 1996) and Windows NT (released in 1993). A string in Java or NT is, at its most fundamental, a sequence of 16-bit values.

UTF-8 was devised in 1992, as a format for encoding Unicode/UCS values as a self-synchronising sequence of bytes in a form suitable for use in Unix filenames, on the web and in other ASCII-based environments. In most cases, it was also smaller than the 16-bit fixed-width representation.

It became clear that 16 bits was not enough. ISO wanted to expand the code space to 32-bit. Unicode did not like this idea because of memory usage concerns and because software was already using 16-bit. There was a compromise: Unicode 2.0 in 1996 expanded the code space to just over 20 bits, and introduced UTF-16

UTF-8 was able to encode all of the new characters directly, and this was the standard way to do things. However, it did create problems for software that used UCS-2 internally and UTF-8 as a storage format.

Adopting "standard UTF-8" for such software would cause compatibility issues. If a new version of the software wrote a supplementary character, the old version of the software would have no way to handle the 4-byte sequence. It would likely either give an error, or mangle the text.

Whereas by using the UTF-16 encoded in UTF-8 format, there would be no need to change the routines that saved and loaded strings at all. There would be no need to change formats at all. From the perspective of old software, the new characters would just be regarded as pairs of unknown characters.

Java's variant has one other change. It uses a 2-byte code for code point zero. My understanding is that this was done to allow the string to be processed safely with standard C string handling routines, even if the Java string contained null characters.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144310/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-green-why-do-java-classfiles-and-jni-use-a-fran); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 16):

At the time Java was designed, it was not at all clear that UTF-8 would emerge as the most commonly used Unicode representation. It was generally assumed that "Unicode" meant "two byte characters", as implemented for example in the Win32 API of Windows NT ([released 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT)). This can also be seen in the Java 16-bit `char` type ([released 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))). Java and the JVM were originally completely implemented using 16-bit characters. Java began life as the ["Oak" programming language in 1991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#History), but it's hard to say how much changed between then and 1995. The precursors to UTF-8 (FSS-UTF) were only invented [around 1992-1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History). UTF-8 itself was not finally adopted by the IETF [until 1998](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2277).

As it turned out, 16-bit characters was not enough for what Unicode eventually became, which meant Java had to expand their representation while still being compatible with the older 16-bit character representation. I can't find specific references to when Unicode "surrogate pairs" were developed, but they were [introduced to Windows in Windows 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows).

In short, Unicode character encodings were going through a number of different transformations in the 1990s. Java and Windows are two major pieces of software developed during that time, and the legacy of their various choices are still very visible today.

Comment: Looks like surrogate pairs were part of Unicode 2.0 (July 1996)

Comment: It looks like Java was started in 1991 and the UTF-8 encoding designed in late 1992.    They probably didn't have time to reconsider this later, when Java was put in the Netscape browser.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing is that a Java string with their modified UTF-8 encoding can have *no* **embedded** null (zero) bytes. This is for C compatibility (in the implementation, and in the JNI) java strings are C-strings with null *termination*).  But the code point `\000` *is* valid UTF-8.  They just chose to use a non-standard encoding of the code point `\000` and **IMO UTF-8 should have done it that way anyway** given the prevalence in the real world in production of C-style APIs.

The other difference - no 4byte encodings - is most likely because in those days there was nothing interesting in that part of the Unicode spec - beyond the BMP - and thus it was an implementation complexity of no value.  In those days implementation complexity *was a big deal* because of where Java was *originally* intended to be used/deployed: toasters and other devices with dinky computing resources.

Internally they used *fixed size* 16 bit characters because the approach Sun adopted for Unix - fixed size **32 bit characters** - was totally a non-starter for their use cases.  And nobody uses *variable length* coding internally because multi-byte character sets are a correctness and performance nightmare.

Comment: Rust uses UTF-8 internally and https://utf8everywhere.org/ argues for everyone to do it because doing anything with codepoints rather than either bytes or extended grapheme clusters is [wrong 99% of the time](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/14/stop-ascribing-meaning-to-unicode-code-points/). (See also https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/ and https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/15/breaking-our-latin-1-assumptions/) Raku does some kind of thing with ropes and baked-in Unicode tables to allow O(1) indexing and iterating by extended grapheme clusters.)

Comment: TL;DR: 99% of the things where you'd think "I'll iterate/index/etc. codepoints" will mangle or otherwise cause problems with various non-European languages that don't have legacy-compat precombined forms in Unicode or have writing systems too complex to be represented that way.

Comment: I personally have never seen an application for embedded null characters in strings.  Just curious... does anyone have any practical examples of those being useful?

Comment: @ssokolow - i'm sure that's very nice for a 2020+ point of view.  But things were different when Java was built - and it was built then.

Comment: @JoelFan - sometimes misguided people do things like encode _multiple_ independent strings into one "string" thing, separate by nulls.  Only works of course for strings with _counts_, not C-strings.  Sometimes other misguided people think they can use a "string" thing to hold a binary blob.  Only works of course for strings with _counts_, not C-strings.  And then, of course, there are the hackers ... who take advantage of the fact that sometimes a string with _count_ is passed to an API that takes a C-string, fun ensues.

Comment: @davidbak: If a language fails to provide a binary blob types other than strings, programmers who need binary blobs shouldn't be blamed for using strings for that purpose.

Comment: *UTF-8 should have done it that way anyway*  Why?  The need for UTF-8 to embed the null character is exactly the same as the need for ASCII to embed the null character. Some system designers design systems that don't permit embedded nulls. Why should UTF-8 go out of its way so that a system designed to not permit embedded nulls can have embedded nulls?

Comment: @JoelFan Since JSON specifies that binary nulls are valid in JSON strings and they're the only byte not allowed in POSIX paths, I [use null codepoints](https://gist.github.com/ssokolow/0d9f5c5e4a8a37a962875af205bcc723) as an escape character for round-tripping POSIX paths through JSON's must-be-UTF8 strings while guaranteeing that any valid POSIX path that *is* valid UTF-8 will have the same raw and encoded representation. (A null byte followed by a codepoint in the 00-FF range indicates a literal byte of that value rather than part of a UTF-8 bytestream.)

Comment: Beyond that, I imagine they exist for the same reason precomposed glyphs do... guaranteed round-tripping compatibility with legacy content encodings. In this case, probably applications written in Pascal, since Pascal uses counted rather than terminator-delimited strings. I know nulls are allowed in NT kernel object manager paths because the NT kernel uses counted strings internally.

Comment: @davidbak I was replying to "And nobody uses variable length coding internally because multi-byte character sets are a correctness and performance nightmare." with counter-examples.

Comment: @JoelFan Aside from the already mentioned applications, null bytes are sometimes used as record separators for command input/output in a number of shell commands on UNIX-like systems (for example, `find` usually has a `-print0` option that produces output like this). This usage is essentially a compatibility hack, because a newline is treated as a record separator by the shell in many cases (which in turn means that a lot of tools treat it that way too, so using null bytes instead provides a way to work with strings with embedded newlines without mangling the newlines).

Comment: _UTF-8 should have done it that way_ No, because that would have broken backward-compatibility with ASCII, which was an important goal of UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

[Throughout the remainder of this post, I'm going to use "UCS-2", "UCS-4", "UTF-8" (etc.) as they're current interpreted, even though most of those terms didn't exist at the time.]

When Java was new, there were basically only two choices available. Unicode promised (but in the long term, didn't deliver) encoding everything in 16-bits per code point (UCS-2).

The alternative was ISO-10646, which didn't specify encoding, as such. But it used 32-bit code points, and lacking a specification of anything else, at the time that was generally interpreted as meaning UCS-4.

Each of those has problems, but the problems with ISO-10646 were serious in the short term, while the problems with Unicode were much longer term.

The big controversy with Unicode at the time was something called "Han unification". Chinese and Japanese alphabets contain quite a few similar characters. Han unification used a single code point for both the Chinese and Japanese versions of many of those. Quite a few people (especially Chinese and Japanese people) didn't like that much (like: hated it with the blinding fury of a supernova).

The big problem with ISO-10646 (as it was seen at the time) was that it needed 32 bits per character. Hard drive prices were falling to the point that using more space for text was seen as somewhat reasonable, but quadrupling the size of nearly all text files was generally seen as just a bit too much.

UTF-8 *had* been invented at the time, but it wasn't particularly well known. Worse, Shift-JIS (among others) had created a *strong* distaste for variable width encoding schemes among many programmers. While UTF-8 avoided many of the worst problems, the simple fact that it was a variable-width encoding was enough for *many* programmers to reject it out of hand.

So, at the time Sun was faced with two (or conceivably three) choices: ISO-10646/UCS-4, ISO-1646/UTF-8, or Unicode/UCS-2.

I'm going to go on record as saying that if they'd chosen either of the ISO-10646 options, Java would have been still-born--long since dead and forgotten except in a footnote in an appendix about "otherwise promising projects killed by a single mistake that was understandable but still utterly bone-headed given the constraints of the time".

So in the short term, UCS-2 was really their only choice. Not a *great* choice by any means, but at least one that allowed Java to remain viable long enough for its early choices to turn into problems people still cared about decades later. And yes, they were faced with a bit more than just UCS-2 vs. UTF-16<sup>1</sup>. By the time they dealt with making that move, quite a bit of software had been written taking advantage of lots of quirks in both UCS-2 itself, and how Java happened to implement parts of it. They needed to account for both, which resulted in something that's fairly kludgy at best.

---

<sup>1. Or at least a fairly reasonable approximation of each.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: conforming UTF-8, as presently defined, cannot encode some valid (to Java) Java `String`s**, on account of disallowing code sequences encoding surrogate code points.

---

In the beginning, Java chose 16-bit Unicode code points for representing characters.  That was perhaps short-sighted, but 16 bits was sufficient for all of Unicode at the time.  Correspondingly, Java's primitive `char` type is 16-bits wide, and, uniquely among Java's primitive types, it is unsigned.

Such a representation is a bit unwieldy for a C-based JVM implementation, however, because raw Java character data tends to contain lots of null bytes, making it unsuitable for use with C string functions.  To much the same degree, the Java representation also tends to be larger, which is unfortunate for storage-constrained devices.  Such devices were definitely among Java's initial targets.

The UTF-8 of the time addressed both of these issues, which made it a good choice for the native-code representation of Java string data.  It's unclear why Sun chose a variant encoding of code point 0 (which still contains a null byte), but there are at least two plausible explanations:

- it helps distinguish between embedded Java char's with value 0 and C string terminators; and
- it makes certain kinds of potential JVM string-handling bugs easier to troubleshoot.

These are not mutually exclusive.

And since the Unicode code point space did not provide for code points wider than 16 bits, and no code points were reserved (e.g. for surrogates), that one variant encoding was the only difference between Java's character encoding and standard UTF-8.  Moreover, it's a pretty benign difference, because a UTF-8 decoder has to go out of its way to reject the Java variant-zero.  A naive UTF-8 decoder will just decode it to code point 0, which is exactly what it in fact represents.

So Java pretty much chose UTF-8, not some amalgamation.  And then UTF-8 was yanked out from under it.

When Unicode widened the code point space and created surrogate pairs and UTF-16, it also specified that UTF-8 encodings of surrogate code points were invalid code sequences.  That made Java's (and others') existing practice non-conforming.  But why should Sun have cared?  They had working software, and the character representation Java used internally was, after all, internal.  They stuck with it.

And Sun didn't particularly pivot on `String`s, either.  To this day, they are sequences of 16-bit unsigned integer values corresponding to Unicode code points in the BMP (including surrogates).  Java does produce and consume UTF-16 surrogate pairs inside strings, but it does not forbid arbitrary placement of surrogate code points within.  In this sense, `String`s' character-data nature is not quite complete.  It was much later that Java introduced code-point-based interfaces to `String`s, which must effectively perform UTF-16 decoding of the character data, and the traditional `char` based interfaces are still available and widely used.

So, Sun just continuing to do what they were already doing is what moved Java from slightly-quirky-if-that UTF-8 to the *bona fide*-variant UTF-8 now known as CESU-8.  But **they couldn't move to UTF-8 even if they wanted to do, because Java `String`s' allowance for unpaired surrogates makes them impossible to encode in conforming UTF-8**.  I suppose it's a bonus that it's easier to transcode Java `String` data to CESU-8 and back, exactly because there is a one-to-one correspondence between CESU-8 code sequences and Java `char`s.   No interpretaion of surrogate pairs is required.

Comment: Why couldn't they have used a version of UTF-8 that simply allowed unpaired surrogates, instead of creating the much-less-standard CESU-8?

Comment: Obviously, @JoelFan, they could have chosen any encoding they wanted.  I can't tell you for sure why they made a decision different from what you suggest, but I can say that it's likely the same decision *I* would have made under the circumstances.  Again, they started with pretty much standard UTF-8, and changed nothing from that point on.  I don't see how changing to an encoding such as you describe would have served any useful purpose for them.  And I guess it's a matter of opinion whether such an alternative is well characterized as more standard than CESU-8.

Comment: Because then the coding from UTF-16 into UTF-8 is context-sensitive: the translation of the current **char** depends on the following **char**.  If a proper pair is present, translate as the codepoint represented by the pair. Otherwise (unpaired, or reverse-paired) translate independently.

Comment: It's also worth emphasizing, @JoelFan, that Java does not use CESU-8 to encode Unicode code point sequences.  That would indeed be weird.  Java uses it to encode sequences of 16-bit code units, for which it seems a more natural fit than standard UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode for Java is (or at least was at the time) strictly 16 bit character - as Unicode was as well a 16 bit code space. Within this 16 bit code surrogate code points (pairs) opened a way to extend the 2^16 character points by another 2^20 ones.

[CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) in turn is an encoding that for one allows to use the same address space, but at the same time guarantees that any conversion to Unicode will result in one or two valid 16 bit characters. As a result any program using a 16 bit character type will be able to handle them.

It essentially transposes the same mechanic 16 bit Unicode uses to UTF-8.

Comment: While Java was originally strictly 16 bit character, it long ago gained 32 bit codepoint counterparts to char APIs, e.g. String.codepointAt() vs String.charAt()

Comment: @ninjalj So? JNI need to be compatible.

Comment: _Unicode for Java is (or at least was at the time) strictly 16 bit character_ My point was that the word _is_ there should probably be _was_

Comment: @ninjalj Sorry, you lost me. It's there, you even cite it.